# WKInterfaceButton IBAction is sending nil sender

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfaceobject

```
2015-05-02 23:56:34.047 TapIt WatchKit Extension[1398:18615] b: <WKInterfaceButton: 0x6080000580c0>
2015-05-02 23:56:34.048 TapIt WatchKit Extension[1398:18615] sender: (null)

- (IBAction)tapped:(id)sender {
    bool success = false;
    NSLog(@"b: %@", b);
    NSLog(@"sender: %@", sender);
```

Why is this coming through nil?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WatchKit actions don't include the sender as an argument. That's why you're seeing `nil`. In this case, your method should really just be `- (IBAction)tapped`.